# Jquery radio button submit repeats same value multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have problems creating report system. Plan is this: User has 4 radios to select and then submits one of them. First submission inserts only one row in mysql but every after that submission inserts more and more rows. Here is the code:

**profile.php**

```
<form id="myform">
  bully<input type="radio" id='radio<?php echo $outid; ?>' name="nein" class='radspam' value="bulinput"> </input><br>
  spam<input type="radio" id='radio<?php echo $outid; ?>'  name="nein" class='radspam' value="spaminput"> </input><br>
  viol<input type="radio" id='radio<?php echo $outid; ?>'   name="nein" class='radspam' value="vioinput"> </input><br>
  pron<input type="radio" id='radio<?php echo $outid; ?>'  name="nein" class='radspam' value="pcont_input"> </input>        
</form>

///jquery code
$(".report").click(function(){
  var parent=$(this).parent().attr("id");
  var split=parent.split("output");
  var id=split[1];
  loading();
  closeloading(); // fadeout loading

  $(".torep").fadeIn("fast"); // fadein popup div
  $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
  $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("fast");

  $("input:radio[name=nein]").click(function() {
    $(".repyes").removeAttr("disabled");
  }); 

  $(".repyes").click(function(){
    var username="<?php echo $username; ?>";
    var valara = $('input:radio[name=nein]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
      url:"s/report.php",
      data:"username=" + username + "&what=" + valara + "&whatid=" + id,
      type:"POST",
      success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

**report.php**

```
<?php
  include "db.php";

  IF (isset($_POST['whatid'])){
    $what=$_POST['what'];
    $reported=$_POST['username'];
    $whatid=$_POST['whatid'];

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO report(reported,what,whatid,date) VALUES ('$reported','$what','$whatid',now())");

    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
      echo "udje";
    }else{
      echo mysql_error();
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: post the generated html of the form.

Comment: Have some valuable advice for you. The `mysql_*` functions you are using are no longer supported and will be removed from future versions of PHP - use PDO or MySQLi instead. Also, you are putting POST data directly in your SQL query. This is open to an SQL injection attack. Use parameter queries instead or sanitize your input thoroughly before using it.

Comment: Why  $(".repyes").click(function(){...}) is within the $('.report').click() function ..?

Comment: .report click popups the div and repyes actually submits the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `id` to global scope. And assign `click` event to `.repyes` outside of `$(".report").click()`:

```
var _id = null;
$(".report").click(function(){
  var parent=$(this).parent().attr("id");
  var split=parent.split("output");
  _id = split[1];
  loading();
  closeloading(); // fadeout loading

  $(".torep").fadeIn("fast"); // fadein popup div
  $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
  $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("fast");
  $(".report").click(function() {
    $("input:radio[name=nein]").click(function() {
      $(".repyes").removeAttr("disabled");
    }); 
  });
});
$(".repyes").click(function(){
    var username="<?php echo $username; ?>";
    var valara = $('input:radio[name=nein]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
      url:"s/report.php",
      data:"username=" + username + "&what=" + valara + "&whatid=" + _id,
      type:"POST",
      success:function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It most likley is because you have an event handler binding inside an event handler. So everytime you click report a new click event is bound to .repeyes

```
$(".report").click(function(){
    ...
    $(".repyes").click(function(){
```

Just move the second binding outside of the first one.

**UPDATE**

Oh, the id issue should be fixed like in [Arthur Halma'S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741748/jquery-radio-button-submit-repeats-same-value-multiple-times/20741939#20741928) by moving it to global scope.